# Converting JSON Array to Java Object when Array Elements Could Be Different

Tags: java, json

Could anyone offer suggestions on a JSON library or code snippet that deals with converting a JSON file such as the one below to a Java object when there could be different key-value pairs in each array element?

```
{
"tweets": [
    {
        "filter_level": "medium",
        "retweeted_status": {
            "contributors": null,
            "text": "",
            "entities": {
                "symbols": [

                ],
                "urls": [

                ],
                "hashtags": [

                ],
                "user_mentions": [

                ]
            },
            "more data":". . ." 
            "user": {
                "user data":". . .",
                . . .
            },
        },
        "contributors": null,
        "text": "",
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [

            ],
            "urls": [

            ],
            "hashtags": [

            ],
            "user_mentions": [
                {
                    "id": 32943506,
                    "name": "Jazzmen",
                    "indices": [
                        3,
                        17
                    ],
                    "screen_name": "_PumpsAndJays",
                    "id_str": "32943506"
                }
            ]
        },
        "more data":". . .",
        "user": {
                "user data":". . .",
                . . .
            },
    },
    { //BEGIN NEW ELEMENT, As you can see this next element doesn't have the
      "retweeted_status" key, so it's different from the element of the array before.

        "filter_level": "medium",
        "contributors": null,
        "text": "",
        "more data like the last element":". . .", . . .
```

I would like to convert a json object like this, made up of an array of "tweets" with information for each, but I cannot find any documentation on a case when the data differs slightly from element to element. In this specific case, an element may be a retweet or just a normal tweet. I would like to know if anyone has insight on how to do this conversion using a library like Jackson, Google Gson, or the like?

I have done a TON of research on this, read multiple tutorials, the documentation for multiple parser libraries and cannot find anything like this.

Comment: So, convert to a Map (containing other Maps and Lists as need be), then work through the contents of the Map to translate your data.  (Hint:  Make a Tweet class which has a constructor that accepts a Map.  If necessary, examine the array element (which would be a Map) before invoking the constructor to decide between creating a Tweet or a Retweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to have the following class:

```
class Tweets {
     public List<Map<String, Object> tweets;
}
```

Using Jackson and passing this class as the desired output will deserialize the JSON without errors, but you need to know the exact name of the fields for each tweet so that you can do .get("field_name") for them. You will also need to cast the value to what you know it to be: String, Integer, Map for nested objects, etc. This code will be hard to maintain.

Another option is to have a Tweet class that has all the possible values you expect from all variations on the tweet objects received. So add retweetedStatus even if it might not have it for certain objects in the array. Jackson will just leave the value as null if it's not present in the input.

```
class Tweets {
     public List<Tweet> tweets;
}

class Tweet {
     String filterLevel;
     RetweetedStatus retweetedStatus;
     String text;
     // + any other fields you may receive and want to deserialize
}

// + any other classes the define nested objects like RetweetedStatus
```

You can even configure Jackson to ignore fields that are not mapped in your class if you want to ignore any fields in the json.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

or by annotating the class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyDtoIgnoreUnknown { ... }
```

You can also use annotations to specify a different name for the variable than the one in the json:

```
@JsonProperty("retweeted_status")
public RetweetedStatus retweetedStatus
```

Notice the change from underscore separated to camelCase

Comment: Thank you SO much. If I could upvote your answer I would. One final question, given that I need to add a nested "user" class, nested "entities" class, and the "retweeted_status" class that should be part of each overall tweet in the list, should I make those classes within the "Tweet" class you defined, or outside of it? I understand you have it outside, but I guess my question is, will Jackson still recognize the "user", "entities", etc. classes as part of the overall list of tweets if they are defined outside of the Tweet class?

Comment: Yes you can (and probably should, especially if you have a large hierarchy) add the classes outside the Tweet class, and it should work no problem. Also I upvoted the question, you may be able to vote now.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies the scope of Jackson Data Binding for me. I am a meager 5 reputation away from upvoting. I will come back to this answer when I have it. Once again, thank you.